# how can I search the saved number

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I want to create a program to save country code and search the country code. Also, there are at most 20 counters for saving country code. I am a new java beginner. I want to know what is the correct way to write the searchCoutryCode
method by using arrays to search the saved country code before?

```
public static void createCountryCode(String countryName, String countrycode) {  
    if (nameCounter >= 20) {                               
        System.out.println("Full");          
    } else {
        System.out.println("Saving the number of " + countryName + ":" + countryCode);           
    }   

    countryNameRec[countryNameCounter++] = countryName;                 
    countryCounterRec[countryCounter++]= countryCode;
}

public static void searchCoutryCode(String countryName) {
    for(int i = 0; i <=20; i++){
        if(countryNameRec[i].equals(countryName)){
            System.out.println("countryNameRec[i]+ " : "+ coutryCodeRec[i]");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No records"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *saved country code before?* where ? in file or memory ?

Comment: This also doesn't compile, check your quotation marks!

Comment: By correct, do you mean efficient?  There are many correct ways, but they may differ in how efficient they are.  Had you stored in a Map, the lookup is fast.  If the array is sorted, the lookup can be fast.  If the array is random, the lookup is slowest

Comment: memory by using arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes country names are unique. In your code you were giving a message about, list size full but adding records anyway. For this kind of problems as recomended by others using maps more suitable.

```
public static HashMap<String,String> countries = new HashMap<>();

public static void createCountryCode(String countryName, String countrycode) {
    if (countries.size() >= 20) {
        System.out.println("Full");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Saving the number of " + countryName + ":" + countrycode);
        countries.put(countryName,countrycode);
    }
}

public static void searchCoutryCode(String countryName) {
    String countryCode = countries.get(countryName);
    if(countryCode == null){
        System.out.println("No records");
    }

    else{
        System.out.println("countryName+ " : "+ countryCode");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use jdk 7 or up for inferred types.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Answer (score 0):

Iterating in an array to find an element  is not an efficient way.
Well, as you have only 20 elements, it will very probably not cause a real issue but whatever you could have more elements to handle later and this way of doing is besides verbose.

Using a `binarySearch (Arrays.binarySearch())` with a sorted array or using a `Map` would be probably better.

Note that actually your `searchCoutryCode()` doesn't return nothing. 
A search method have to return something : the element that it founds or nothing. 
You could return `String` :

```
public static String searchCoutryCode(String countryName) {
   ...
}
```

or better `Optional<String>` to handle in a cleaner way the not found case :

```
public static Optional<String> searchCoutryCode(String countryName) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend learning about Maps. They're a smarter version of arrays, and act like dictionaries with "keys" being like the words and "values" being like a definition. Your entire method can be replaced using a call to the containsValue() or containsKey() method from the java library.

However, if you want to use arrays, i would recommend looking into the binary search methods which are part of the Java Arrays library.